# Please explain the meaning of the sentence

Tags: translation

I am trying to understand the following excerpt:

> 有时候灭掉不如引导。

What does this sentence mean anyway?

Comment: Sometimes, it is not the best means to eliminate, to guide the direction of the good is.

Comment: Changing it other than destroying it.

Comment: I know this question is rather old, but for the future reader, please don't ask for a translation without further details, e.g., putting the words in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You should supply more context.

有时候 Sometimes 灭掉 eliminate/destroy 不如 not as good as 引导 lead/guide。

In a political context maybe:

It is better not to seek to destroy your adversaries but to guide them.

Or if the context is bad habits:

It is better to seek guidance rather than try (yourself) to eradicate a bad habit.

Comment: I took it from some wuxia novel. 

“这样啊，那就太好了，我期待你成为魔门门主的那一天，有时候灭掉不如引导。”

Answer (score 0):

Considering the context: “这样啊，那就太好了，我期待你成为魔门门主的那一天，有时候灭掉不如引导。”

The sentence means: I'd rather to guide a person like you than destroying you.

Answer (score 0):

It means something like "sometimes it is better to guide your opponent and make him/her your friend (or lead him/her in the direction that you want) rather than to destroy him/her."

I'm not quite sure if my explanation really fit in the context. Hopefully it will help you understand the sentence.